# Difference between 'OR' and '||' in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What's the difference between '`OR`' and '`||`' in SQL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`OR` is *boolean* operator, e.g.

```
   (a = b) OR (c = d)
```

when `||` is *string concatenation*, e.g.

```
  'a' || 'b'
```

Comment: There are 11 `||` operators in PostgreSQL for different types of arguments, not only for strings.

Comment: @Abelisto: you're quite right, it's not necessary, that both arguments of *string concatenation* should be strings, and lines `'a' || 123`, `123 || 'a'` are possible (result will be string, however: `'a123'`, `'123a'`).

Comment: I am talking about that it can be not only strings but also an arrays, for example, `array[1,2,3] || array[4,5]` gives result `array[1,2,3,4,5]` which is not a sting at all. Moreover you can to define your own operator `||` with boolean arguments.

Comment: While this is standard, it should be noted that in MySQL (if Giovanni or someone else learning from this) the `||` operator by default is the same as `OR`. It can be made to use the standard behavior by setting the `sql_mode` variable either for the session or globally. The possible settings for it are described in the manual under "5.1.7 Server SQL Modes".

Comment: In MySQL these operators '||' and 'OR'  is boolean operators?

Answer (score 4):

In SQL `'OR'` is an operator that specifies that either of two conditions needs to be met, while `'||'` is concatenation.